# Laravel: How can I merge tags from two items into one new item

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm writting a little application which has "companies" as an entity. These companies can be tagged.

I have a function which allows me to merge two companies into a new company. As companies can have many tags and one tag can be assigned to many companies there is a many-to-many relationship.

When creating/editing a company I can save/update the tags using `$company->tags()->snyc($tags)`

But now I also want the new company to have all the tags from the old two companies. How can a manage to do that?

Greetings Luca

Comment: $newCompany->tags()->attach($oldCompany->tags->pluck(‘id’))?

Comment: That is just a function for one old company, but there are multiple (at least 2) but it gave me a push into the right direction, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Select tags that two old companies have:

```
$tags = Tags::whereExists(function ($q) use($companyId1, $companyId2) {
    $q->select(DB::raw(1))
        ->from('company_tags')
        ->whereIn('company_id', [$companyId1, $companyId2])
        ->whereRaw('company_tags.tag_id=tags.id');
})->get();
```

Then sync these tags to new company:

```
$newCompany->sync($tags->pluck('id')->toArray());
```